# ParseException when reading table in Spark fails

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, delta-lake

I'm trying to read a table in spark using a string path but I get the following error:

```
spark.read.format("delta").table(path)

Possibly unquoted identifier spark-warehouse detected. Please consider quoting it with back-quotes as `spark-warehouse`(line 1, pos 5)
```

The table that I'm trying to read is found on my local machine under `spark-warehouse`.

I tried the option of adding back-quotes to the path but it failed again giving me a different error

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Table or view not found: 

'UnresolvedRelation [spark-warehouse/data/temp/myuser/unit_test/_delta/test/table], [], false
```

I've checked the path for correctness. For example if I use `load` method it works fine.

```
spark.read.format('delta').load(path)
```

I wonder if the issue is `-` in `spark-warehouse`?

I would like to know why read.table fails.